# Algun ejemplo de OCR vision text para android

Tags: android, android-studio, ocr

¿Alguien tiene un ejemplo de ocr  que detecte el texto con la camara y que este funcionando?.

Ya he buscado y he seguido el tutorial de google este:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mobile-vision-ocr/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#6

y no me funciona  ya cambie la version de  las dependencias

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.0.0+'
```

y sigue sin funcionar al parecer no descarga la dependecia  de OCR.

En mi dispositivo tengo 2 gb libres de memoria interna.

Alguien que me pueda ayudar con un ejemplo funcional gracias.

Comment: Hola Jesus, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Podemos ayudarte con el problema particular que tienes si explicas mejor qué hiciste y qué errores te dió. En cuanto al ejemplo que pides, es mejor que lo busques en internet. Mira [ask] y [help/on-topic] para aprender a hacer preguntas válidas y de calidad. Un saludo.